# C++ Roman Numeral Converter output from?

Tags: c++, roman-numerals

So this program is supposed to output to the console "Enter a negative number to end. Enter an arabic number between 1 and 3999:" then you give it your number, it breaks it down and converts it. I am getting output that looks like this 
1
9
8
4
and I have NO IDEA what part of my code this is being enacted.

code looks like this

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;

string convert(int digit, string low, string mid, string high); 


 int main()
{
    const int MAX_INPUT = 3999, MIN_INPUT = 0,      
    ARRAY_SIZE = 4;         
    string answers[ARRAY_SIZE] = { "", "", "", "" };        
    int accumulator = 0;                            
    int userNum = 0;                        
do {    

    cout << "Enter a negative number to end the program.\n";
    cout << "Enter an arabic number between 1 and 3999: ";

    while (!(cin >> userNum) || (userNum < MIN_INPUT || userNum > MAX_INPUT)){              //input validation
        if (userNum < 0)
        {
            cout << "Exiting program:";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');                    
            cout << "\nInvalid Value. Number must be between 1 and 3999:  ";
        }
    }

    // Digit Extraction - turns userNum into four seperate values
    int thous = userNum / 1000;                                 //thousands place value
    int hund = userNum % 1000 / 100;                            //hundreds place value
    int tens = userNum % 100 / 10;                              //tens place value
    int ones = userNum % 10 / 1;                                //ones place    value



    // filling answers array with results from convert function. 
    answers[0] = convert(thous, "M", "M", "M");
    answers[1] = convert(hund, "C", "D", "M");
    answers[2] = convert(tens, "X", "L", "C");
    answers[3] = convert(ones, "I", "V", "X");

    cout << "Roman numeral for " << userNum << " is: ";
    cout << answers[0]  << answers[1] <<  answers[2];
    cout <<  answers[3] << endl;




    } while (userNum > 0);

    system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
 }


 // convert function

 string convert(int digit, string low, string mid, string high)
{

cout << digit << endl;

if (digit == 1)
{
    return low;
}
if (digit == 2)
{
    return low + low;
}
if (digit == 3)
{
    return low + low + low;
}
if (digit == 4)
{
    return low + mid;
}
if (digit == 5)
{
    return mid;
}
if (digit == 6)
{
    return mid + low;
}
if (digit == 7)
{
    return mid + low + low;
}
if (digit == 8)
{
    return mid + low + low + low;
}
if (digit == 9)
{
    return low + high;
}
if (digit == 0)
{
    return "";
}
}
```

Comment: the erroneous output is the one that has 1 9 8 4 each on a seperate line.

Comment: What compiler accepts `ARRAY_SIZE = 4;` without complaining?

Comment: Run your code step by step in the debugger to find which part of your code is doing that. Or read, and pay attention to all lines that output something ...

Comment: visual studio.. it says const int .......... then it lists three or four contant values on the same line - see the comma

Comment: You're writing to `cout` inside `convert `.

Comment: Erroneous output is coming from first line in `convert()`: `cout << digit << endl;`

Comment: so my function is printing as well..i thought it was simply returning??

Comment: i have been over this so many times..its the tiny, little things that get me, every time...

Comment: going to take this question down - if I can figure out how.

Comment: Here's one strategy in the future for troubleshooting (debugging) your code in the future and helping you get faster answers when you're still stumped: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the line `cout << digit << endl;` from the function `convert()`.